# Python interfaces for documentation

Tags: python, python-3.x, interface

I understand that in Python we use duck-typing instead of implementing a concrete interface.

So if you have a function that takes in an animal object that needs to be able to eat and drink, you can just call `.eat()` and `.drink()` and whatever object passed in just needs to make sure to include those methods whatever way suits them.

There is no need to make an interface that everyone implements when calling your function.

But for the sake of documentation and the new Python3 type-hints, is there any proper way to create an interface.

Something like ...

```
interface Animal:
    eat()
    drink()

def foo(a: Animal):
    a.eat()
    a.drink()
```

... where the interface `Animal` is purely for documentation and the non-enforced type-hint in the `foo` function. It is never used at runtime, and those passing in animals into the function still follow the duck-typing protocol.

Is this possible in Python?

Comment: Abstract base classes, [ABC](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) for short, might help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use ABC (Abstract Base Classes) for this The base class (read "interface") needs to either have the `metaclass` set to `abc.ABCMeta`, or derive from something that does. You can then use decorators to indicate that methods must be overridden.

```
import abc

class Animal(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def eat(self):
        pass

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def drink(self):
        pass

def foo(a: Animal):
    a.eat()
    a.drink()
```

Properties, class methods, and static methods can also be made abstract by using the normal decorators *before* `@abc.abstractmethod`:

```
@property
@abc.abstractmethod
def data(self):
    return self._data

@classmethod
@abc.abstractmethod
def abstract_classmethod(cls, ...):
    pass

@staticmethod
@abc.abstractmethod
def abstract_staticmethod(...):
    pass
```

---

Here it is in use...

```
In [40]: class Animal(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    ...:     @abstractmethod
    ...:     def eat(self):
    ...:         print('Eats...')
    ...:     @abstractmethod
    ...:     def drink(self):
    ...:         print('Drinks...')
    ...:
    ...:

In [41]: def foo(a: Animal):
    ...:     a.eat()
    ...:

In [42]: class Elephant:
    ...:     def eat(self):
    ...:         print('Elephant eating...')
    ...:     def drink(self):
    ...:         print('Elephant drinking...')
    ...:


In [43]: class Giraffe(Animal):
    ...:     def eat(self):
    ...:         print('Giraffe eats...')
    ...:     def drink(self):
    ...:         print('Giraffe drinks...')
    ...:

In [44]: giraffe = Giraffe()

In [45]: elephant = Elephant()

In [46]: isinstance(giraffe, Animal)
Out[46]: True

In [47]: isinstance(elephant, Animal)
Out[47]: False

In [48]: foo
Out[48]: <function __main__.foo(a: __main__.Animal)>

In [49]: foo(giraffe)
Giraffe eats...

In [50]: foo(elephant)
Elephant eating...

In [51]: foo(Animal())
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-e060be6dff03> in <module>
----> 1 foo(Animal())

TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Animal with abstract methods drink, eat
```

Comment: Thanks this looks good (but a little complicated for a simple interface). I assume that I do **not** need to manually inherit `Animal` for whatever I pass into `foo`? If so, this is perfect

Comment: @DavidCallanan I've edited my answer with an example. I believe it meets your criteria. As far as I am aware, type hinting never stops a function being called, it's just for analysis.

Comment: This is OK; however, in the book Fluent Python it is claimed that python developers rarely use abstract base classes. Developers use informal interfaces all around. There are probably more common ways to describe the interfaces, for example, in the documentation.